# Custom UITableViewCell constraint issue on cell reuse

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` that has a dynamic image height. All the resizing works as its supposed to when the cell is created. The issue is once the cell is reused by the `UITableView` the constraint for the image height is changed and causes an “Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints” error.

I have tried deactivating the height constraint before resetting it but it still causes the error.

With regards to setting the height anchor. This creates a new instance each time, are the deactivated constraints released from memory? Is there a way of just updating the current constraint in this format?

Should i be doing something within - (void)prepareForReuse method?

Thanks for any help

```
// Within Custom UITableViewCell
// The cell is a prototype cell in StoryBoard
// The width of the image is fixed and already set
// Observe when the image is set for imgView

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)change context:(void *)context {

if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"image"]) {
    if(self.imgView.image) {

        CGFloat ratio = self.imgView.image.size.height / self.imgView.image.size.width;
        self.imageHeightConstraint.active = NO;
        self.imageHeightConstraint = [self.imgView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.imgView.widthAnchor multiplier:ratio];
        self.imageHeightConstraint.identifier = @"imageHeightConstraint";
        self.imageHeightConstraint.active = YES;

    }
}
```

}

The `UITableViewCell` auto resizes as the `UIImageView` is in a `UIStackView` which has its top and bottom anchors fixed to the top and bottom of the cells `contentView`.

```
- (void)buildUI {

    UIStackView *containerStackView = [UIStackView new];
    [self.contentView addSubview:containerStackView];
    containerStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    containerStackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal;
    containerStackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistributionFill;
    containerStackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignmentCenter;
    containerStackView.spacing = 10;
    [containerStackView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.contentView.topAnchor constant:10.0].active = YES;
    [containerStackView.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.contentView.centerXAnchor].active = YES;
    [containerStackView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.contentView.widthAnchor multiplier:kImageWidthMultiplier].active = YES;
    [containerStackView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.contentView.bottomAnchor constant:-30.0].active = YES;

    self.imgView = [UIImageView new];
    [containerStackView addArrangedSubview:self.imgView];
    self.imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.imgView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:containerStackView.widthAnchor multiplier:0.492].active = YES;
}
```

Comment: Are you increasing the height of UITableViewCell as well when you are changing the height of imageView? Is `self.imageHeightConstraint` a `weak` or `strong` property?

Comment: Yes the `UITableViewCell` auto resizes to fit the image. `self.imageHeightConstraint` has a `weak` reference.

Comment: Try keeping it as `strong` as it may be `nil` after deactivating the constraint.

Comment: I had already tried that and it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite complicated for calculate dynamic table view cell height. In you case, cell height depend on image height.

When table view cell is reused, all cell's properties will be reused and the height is not exception. The easy way to make change is using `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, but it very hard when using autolayout to calculate height.

According this article (http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975). The subview in table view cell will be compressed and after that, we could easy to get height and return in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. However, it take a little time to calculate and make your scroll is not smooth, but we could using `estimatedRowHeight`, your tableview will use the estimate height and apply for specific row before we can calculated exactly height for this row

The below is short demo code:

```
//Estimate height (height could be 35, 42, 50, 29, etc)
//Just estimate a number
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        return 40.0f;
}

//Your exactly height for row
- (CGFloat)calculateHeightForConfiguredSizingCell:(UITableViewCell *)sizingCell {
    [yourCustomCell setNeedsLayout];
    [yourCustomCell layoutIfNeeded];

    CGSize size = [yourCustomCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
    return size.height;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //only set once
    static YourCustomTableViewCell *yourCustomCell = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        //load custom cell
        yourCustomCell = (YourCustomTableViewCell*)[Utils getCellNibFile:@"YourCustomTableViewCell" Owner:self];
});
    //get image from datasource
    UIImage* image = [self.dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath];
    //set image for cell and begin calculate height after set image
    [yourCustomCell setImage:image];
    [self calculateHeightForConfiguredSizingCell:yourCustomCell];
    return height;
}
```